# How to get bandwidth usage

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bandwidth

How can I calculate device bandwidth usage percentage using windows API

I tried using `GetIpStatisticsEx`() function but that didn't help

Comment: Overall bandwidth or for a single process or connection?

Comment: Have you tried perfmon yet (performance monitor app that comes with windows)? It should be able to show you some statistics regarding network traffic (per process). Once you know which counters you want , you can also access them from C++: [Accessing Performance Data in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/accessing-performance-data-in-c--?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: ×Overall bandwidth @user4581301

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [GetIfTable function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getiftable?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

GetIfTable function enumerates physical interfaces on a local system and returns this information in a `MIB_IFTABLE structure`.  The MIB_IFTABLE structure contains an interface count and an array of `MIB_IFROW structures` for each interface.